# QNX_HOST environment variable not set

Tags: qnx, qnx-neutrino, blackberry-qnx, qnx-ifs

I am compiling mlpack using QNX.Keep reporting the following errors:
CMake Error at `CMakeLists.txt:28 (message):QNX_HOST environment variable not set!!!`
I have added the following to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set (QNX_HOST “/data/QNX/qnx700/host/linux”)
set (QNX_TARGET “/data/QNX/qnx700/target/qnx7”)
```

I first executed the following command:

```
source /etc/bash.bashrc_qnx qnx_aarch64
source /data/QNX/qnx700/qnxsdp-env.sh
```

=>

```
QNX_HOST=/data/QNX/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64
QNX_TARGET=/data/QNX/qnx700/target/qnx7
MAKEFLAGS=-I/data/QNX/qnx700/target/qnx7/usr/include
```

And `cmake ..` But `sudo make` command still report an error–“`error: environment variables QNX_HOST and QNX_TARGET not defined`”.The following is the content of part document CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME QNX)
set(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME QNX)
set(QNX_PROCESSOR arm)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 7.0.0)
set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING 1)
set( TOOLCHAIN QNX )
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "$ENV{TOOLCHAIN_PATH}")
#set (QNX_HOST "/data/QNX/qnx700/host/linux")
#set (QNX_TARGET "/data/QNX/qnx700/target/qnx7")
set(QNX_HOST "$ENV{QNX_HOST}")
set(QNX_TARGET "$ENV{QNX_TARGET}")
message(STATUS "*********************************")
message(STATUS "${QNX_HOST}")
message(STATUS "${QNX_TARGET}")
message(STATUS "*********************************")
#Check environment variables
if ("$ENV{QNX_HOST}" STREQUAL "")
    #message(FATAL_ERROR "QNX_HOST environment variable not set")
endif()

if ("$ENV{QNX_TARGET}" STREQUAL "")
    #message(FATAL_ERROR "QNX_TARGET environment variable not set")
endif()
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/data/QNX/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-gcc")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/data/QNX/qnx700/host/linux/x86_64/usr/bin/aarch64-unknown-nto-qnx7.0.0-g++")
#set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14) # C++14...
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON) #...is required...
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS ON) #...without compiler extensions like gnu++14
# search for programs in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
# for libraries and headers in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

When I running `make` without sudo, it still report an error–-

```
[ 10%] Linking CXX executable ../../bindings/julia/mlpack/build/bin/generate_jl_sparse_coding
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dpotrf_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dpotri_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `ddot_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgbsvx_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgeqrf_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dposvx_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgemm_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgesdd_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgels_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dnrm2_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dlansy_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dpotrs_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dtrcon_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgesv_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dsyevd_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgbcon_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgbtrs_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dposv_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgetri_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgemv_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgesvd_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgbtrf_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dlange_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dtrtrs_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgecon_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dlangb_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dsyrk_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgetrf_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgesvx_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dpbtrf_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgetrs_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgelsd_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `ilaenv_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dsyev_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgbsv_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dorgqr_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dtrtri_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dgtsv_'
../../../../lib/libmlpack.so.3.4: undefined reference to `dpocon_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/mlpack/methods/sparse_coding/CMakeFiles/generate_jl_sparse_coding.dir/build.make:119: recipe for target 'src/mlpack/bindings/julia/mlpack/build/bin/generate_jl_sparse_coding' failed
make[2]: *** [src/mlpack/bindings/julia/mlpack/build/bin/generate_jl_sparse_coding] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6388: recipe for target 'src/mlpack/methods/sparse_coding/CMakeFiles/generate_jl_sparse_coding.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/mlpack/methods/sparse_coding/CMakeFiles/generate_jl_sparse_coding.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:145: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Does anyone know what should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that you've added the QNX build toolchain to your environment.  QNX provides the 'qnxsdp-env.sh' shell script (or qnx-sdp-env.bat for Windows) to set up the toolchain.  This will set all appropriate environment variables.  Run this script before trying to use any other build commands such as cmake, make, qcc, etc.

Inferring from your example that you're using QNX 7.0 on a Linux host, try:

```
$ source /data/QNX/qnxsdp-env.sh
$ cmake
```

Note that `source` is important: it instructs the shell to run the script such that it can modify the current shell environment, rather than launching it in a subshell.   If you run the script without `source`, the script will have no effect.

Reference: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.prog/topic/devel_OS_version.html

Comment: I still haven't solved this bug. Maybe I didn't describe it clearly before. Now I have made some more detailed description.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  The problem you're having there is using `sudo` to run `make` -- `sudo` clears the environment variables as a way to prevent unwanted or potentially malicious state from leaking in to a root shell.    In general you shouldn't be running `make` for compiling as a root user - apart from environment variable issues, it's also a big security risk.  Try just running `make` without `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But when I running make without sudo, it still report an error.Now I have made some more detailed description.Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Those functions are part of LAPACK, a common linear algebra library.   Assuming it is both a required dependency for mlpack, and that you've already built LAPACK for QNX, then there is probably an issue with cmake finding the correct LAPACK library paths; you'll have to dig through mlpack's cmake configuration to find out how it's detected and correct it.